# Nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got intermitent error when try to use nib that was registered for reuse. Im using the same custom cell on two ViewControllers.

> 2013-09-05 11:04:08.476 xxx[51395:c07] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'invalid nib registered for identifier (TweetTableViewCellId) - nib
>   must contain exactly one top level object which must be a
>   UITableViewCell instance'

1. Im use NIB file with one view at Object list - on top, sure -. It has type TweetViewCell, it that extends UITableViewCell -.
2. I already define [b]identifier[/b] as "*TweetTableViewCellId*"
3. Im load nib and did register it on viewDidLoad (i already debug and nib object aways is loaded)
4. I try to recover registered cell using the same id.

#### some piece of code

```
// First Controller to use custom Cell
@implementation TweetsViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
...
  UINib *nib =  [UINib nibWithNibName:kTweetTableViewCellNibName bundle:nil];
  [self.tweetsTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TweetTableViewCellId"];

..
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  TweetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTweetTableViewCellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
...
}

@end

// second Controller to use custom Cell

@implementation OfflineEpisodeModalViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  UINib *nib =  [UINib nibWithNibName:kTweetTableViewCellNibName bundle:nil];
  [self.tweetSearchTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:kTweetTableViewCellId];
}

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  TweetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TweetTableViewCellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}

@end
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you added UITableViewCell to the xib file? and xib file containing only that one?

Comment: yep, i already declare custom class to my xib file.

Comment: Oh no! I found one xib file - "lost file" - with the same name. i believe that intermitent errors happens when exists two xibs with same name - the behaviour and xib loaded cannot be undefined.

Comment: For me this error was showing because, i had an extra empty Cell inside xib file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RESOLVED

Is simple, but anyway, is valid as a new knowledge: if you declare a xib file with the same name (my mistake), the file that will be loaded isnt  guaranteed.

I delete the "forgotten" xib file and works!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 8):

I had a label that was not under the "content view" in XIB file elements list on left hand side.

I removed that label and it worked.

Comment: Thanks,In my case I've added TapGesture.

Answer (score 0):

You might have two views pointing to the same class in your .xib  Double check your interface files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Add gesture recognisers on cell only from code.
It works for me. I think it's UIKit bug.